# jQuery post form with static value from funnction attributes

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post

I have a funnction to post and recive form to another php file. I don't know why,  but the php file has return empty array.

the function has two attributes "name" and "arg" and wants to send these two values ​​to the file steel_th_dynamic_query.php, then display what it returns in the div "demo". I think the problem is on the line `data: {` but I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
function displayPhrase(name, arg){
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = name + ' ARG: ' + arg;
    $.ajax({
      url: './modules/settings/steel_th_dynamic_query.php',
      data: {
        MyData: name,
        MyARG: arg
      },
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;
      }
    });

}
```

Comment: Remove `processData` and `contentType`. You're not sending a FormData object, so you don't need to set them to `false`. Also double check what values your PHP is receiving

Comment: It's works, Thank u!

Comment: No problem, I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `processData` and `contentType` properties, or at least set them back to their default values. Setting them to `false` is only required when sending binary data in the request, ie. a `FormData` object.

```js
function displayPhrase(name, arg) {
  $.ajax({
    url: './modules/settings/steel_th_dynamic_query.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      MyData: name,
      MyARG: arg
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#demo").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```